# Norms and orthogonality

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to refresh my memory with linear algebra. I am confused with these set of questions:

> 1. Show that $a=\begin{pmatrix}
>      1 \\
>      i  \\
>      -1  \\
>      -i 
>     \end{pmatrix},$ $b=\begin{pmatrix}
>      1 \\
>      -1  \\
>      1  \\
>      -1
>     \end{pmatrix}, $$\ c=\begin{pmatrix}
>      1 \\
>      -i  \\
>      -1  \\
>      i 
>     \end{pmatrix}$ are orthogonal.
> 2. Find $(f,g)$ in $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$ if $f(x)=e^{ix}, \ g(x)=e^{-ix}$.
> 3. Find $||f||$ in $L^2(-1,1)$ if $f(x)=-1$ for $x<0$ and $f(x)=1$ for $x\ge 0$.

For the first question I got that it is not orthogonal since $a\dot\ c\ne 0$.

For the second question I got $2\pi$ since $\int^{\pi}_{-\pi}f(x)g(x)dx=2\pi$, but the answer is $0$?

For the third question the answer is $\sqrt{2}$ which I don't know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot a very important thing:

In $\mathbb{C^n}$ inner product between $(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)$ and $(y_1,y_2,\cdots,y_n)$ is given by $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i\overline{y_i}$.

More generally, the inner product between two functions is $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x)\overline{g(x)} dx$.

Use these to get the correct results.

Comment: Wow, I forgot all about complex conjugates -__-. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$\langle f,g\rangle=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x)\overline{g(x)}\,dx=\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{2\pi x}dx=0.$

$\|f\|_2^2=\int_{-1}^1f^2(x)\,dx=\int_{-1}^1 \,dx=2.$

Comment: How did you get the second one of $||f||$?

Comment: Well $f(x)\overline{f(x)}=f^2(x)=1$ on $[-1,1]$

Comment: But how come the answer is $\sqrt{2}$ instead of $2$?

Comment: I computed $\|\cdot\|_2^2$, so taking square root you get $\sqrt{2}$

Comment: Oh $\|\cdot\|_2$ is the right notation and in here same as $\|\|$ .

Comment: Oh okay, I see now. So $\|\cdot\|_2$ is the same as $\|\|$ which is simply just $(\sum_n|x_n|^2)^{\frac12}$?

Comment: Yeah in space of functions its usually denoted by $L_2$ and in discrete form when you deal with sequence its denoted by $\ell_2$

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up!